# How to receive Mpeg-ts stream over UDP from FFMpeg in Java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, udp, mpeg2-ts

I have a live video stream from FFMpeg, and I am having a hard time viewing the stream using my own custom Java application. Before someone tells me to use VLC or something like that I do want to use my own application. The stream I am trying to read is a H.264 encoded Mpeg-ts stream streamed over UDP. I do know how to decode the H.264 frames, but I am simply wondering about how to receive the Mpeg-ts stream.

Comment: multicast or unicast?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that, unicast.

Comment: Then the device that is sending the data must be configured to send to a specific ip/port. Just open the port and read packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jon Kittel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3131062/jon-kittell) provided a good answer, anyway in the question comments it is mentioned UNICAST communication, so Jon's code is not usable in this case.
A simplified unicast receiver is provided below (credit to [P. Tellenbach](http://www.heimetli.ch) for the original example).

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class DatagramServer
{
   private final static int PACKETSIZE = 2048 ;

   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
    // Check the arguments
    //      if( args.length != 1 )
    //      {
    //         System.out.println( "usage: DatagramServer port" ) ;
    //         return ;
    //      }

      try
      {
         // Convert the argument to ensure that is it valid
         int port = 1234; //Integer.parseInt( args[0] ) ;
         FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("testStream.ts", true);

         // Construct the socket
         DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket( port ) ;

         System.out.println( "The server is ready..." ) ;

         DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( new byte[PACKETSIZE], PACKETSIZE ) ;
         for( ;; )
         {
            // Receive a packet (blocking)
            socket.receive( packet );
            try {
                output.write(packet.getData());
            } finally {
                output.close();
            }
        }  
     }catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This client will listen for UDP stream on localhost address, port 1234, and will write each received packet into testStream.ts file.
If the stream is H.264 encoded Mpeg-ts, the outputfile can be opened in any moment with a player to reproduce the video stream captured until that moment.

Answer (score 1):

In order the receive the multicast stream you will need to create a multicast client that has a buffer to store the video data and uses a socket that can join and listen for multicast streams.

The two properties are the multicast address (239.1.1.1) and the port (49410).

Using ffmpeg start streaming a mp4 video file to a multicast address and port.

```
ffmpeg -i .\mars.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -f mpegts udp://239.1.1.1:49410
```

Compile and run the multiclass client which uses the [MulticastSocket](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) class to join the multicast group and listen for the UDP stream packets. We pass the buffer into the [DatagramPacket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html) object and when the socket receives the UDP packet the buffer is filled with the mpeg-ts data. Then you can copy the buffer to another part of the application to decode the data.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {

    final static String INET_ADDR = "239.1.1.1";
    final static int PORT = 49410;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        // Get the multicast address that we are going to connect to.
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(INET_ADDR);

        // Create a buffer of bytes, which will be used to store
        // the incoming bytes containing the information from the streaming server
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

        // Create a new Multicast socket so we can join the multicast group
        try (MulticastSocket clientSocket = new MulticastSocket(PORT)){
            //Joint the Multicast group.
            clientSocket.joinGroup(address);

            // do an infinite loop
            while (true) {
                // Receive the information and print it.
                DatagramPacket msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                clientSocket.receive(msgPacket);

                String data = new String(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                System.out.println("Data ->  " + data);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```